# Does the closed-form solution (given with the pseudo inverse) to an under-determined linear system minimize the $L_2$-norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, pseudoinverse

Suppose we want to solve an under-determined linear system $Ax=b$ (assuming $A$ has full row rank). Then the closed solution can be written as
$$
x=A^T(AA^T)^{-1}b
$$
However, in most cases, when solving under-determined systems we want the solution $x$ to minimize $\|x\|_2$. Does this closed-form solution satisfy this requirement?

I can compute the $L_2$-norm of $x$ as:
$$
\|x\|_2^2=x^Tx=b^T(AA^T)^{-1}AA^T(AA^T)^{-1}b=b^T(AA^T)^{-1}b
$$
But I don't know how to determine whether it is minimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proof based on SVD:

Let
$$
A=U[D,0]V
$$
be the SVD of $A$, where $D$ is the diagonal matrix containing the singular values of $A$. Since $A$ has full row rank, the diagonal entries of $D$ are all nonzero. To solve $Ax=b$ with the SVD algorithm we rewrite it as
$$
[D,0]Vx=U^{-1}b\implies x_{\rm svd}=V^{-1}\left[\matrix{D^{-1}\\0}\right]U^{-1}b
$$
$x$ obtained in this way minimizes the $L_2$-norm within the solution space.

On the other hand, note that
$$
AA^T=UD^2U^{-1}\implies(AA^T)^{-1}=UD^{-2}U^{-1}
$$
so the solution given with the pseudo inverse is
$$
x_{\rm psuedo-inv}=A^T(AA^T)^{-1}b=V^{-1}\left[\matrix{D\\0}\right]U^{-1}UD^{-2}U^{-1}b=V^{-1}\left[\matrix{D^{-1}\\0}\right]U^{-1}b
$$
So
$$
x_{\rm psuedo-inv}=x_{\rm svd}
$$